# how to get primary key ID of one table to automatically insert in another table

Tags: php, mysql

How do you get the latest ID ( primary key id ) of one table and insert it into the foreign key of another table when submitting a form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this,  it applies if you are using **PDO**

```
$id=$dbh->lastInsertId();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a property of mysqli
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score 0):

I think This will help You.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

```
INSERT INTO foo (auto,text)
    VALUES(NULL,'text');         # generate ID by inserting NULL
INSERT INTO foo2 (id,text)
    VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'text');  # use ID in second table
```

Comment: Make sure you use a transaction to group those two `INSERT`s.

Comment: my insert statemets are in different places.. how would last insert work?

Answer (score 0):

if you use mysqli: mysqli_insert_id

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

if you use PDO:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php